# how to get the sum of data till a particular date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe (Date is in YYYY-MM-DD format)

```
Region  Area  Hq   Sales  Date               monthyear
  R1     A1   H1   1000   2020-01-01           202001
  R1     A1   H1   2000   2020-01-05           202001
  R1     A1   H1   1500   2020-01-09           202001
  R1     A1   H1   2000   2020-01-12           202001
  R1     A1   H1   2000   2020-01-17           202001
  R1     A1   H1   1300   2020-01-21           202001
  R1     A1   H1   1000   2020-01-23           202001
  R1     A1   H1   5000   2020-01-27           202001
```

From 1st day of month to 9th Day, the total sales value should be calculated

From 10th day of month to 18th day, the total sales value should be calculated

From 19th day of month to 24th day, the total sales value should be calculated

From 25th day of month to 28th day, the total sales value should be calculated

The desired output:

```
Region    Area  Hq    Sales    till_date    month_year
 R1        A1   H1     4500       9th          202001
 R1        A1   H1     4000       18th         202001
 R1        A1   H1     2300       24th         202001
 R1        A1   H1     5000       28th         202001
```

As you can see, we don't have **2020-01-10**, but we are taking from 2020-01-10 to 2020-01-18th range. So we are taking **12th, 17th's** which falls into that range. Likewise the rest.

Another example ( only one record )

```
Region   Area    Hq    Sales    Date          monthyear
H1        A1     H1    1000     2020-01-01     202001
```

The desired output

```
Region  Area    Hq     Sales     till_date      monthyear
 H1       A1    H1     1000      2020-01-09       202001
```

Before result, the sales is created at 2020-01-01, but it falls in 1st-9th

dates range, the till_date is 2020-01-09.

Additional Explanation:

```
Region  Area   Hq    Sales     Date         monthyear
 H1     A1     H1    2000     2020-01-31      202001
```

Desired output:

```
Region Area   Hq      Sales    till_date   monthyear
 H1     A1    H1        0       NaN           202001
```

Because 31st didn't fall in any of the range, so there's no till_date

I've been trying this a lot but it didn't work out for me. So looking for your help.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1**:

Use `.asfreq` to add all missing dates and use `.isin` to create mask to use with `groupby.sum`

```
a = np.array([1,10,19,25])
df1 = df.set_index('Date').asfreq('D')
m = df1.index.day.isin(a).cumsum()

df_final = df1.groupby(['Region', 'Area', 'Hq', m]).Sales.sum().droplevel(-1).reset_index()

Out[69]:
  Region Area  Hq   Sales
0     R1   A1  H1  4500.0
1     R1   A1  H1  4000.0
2     R1   A1  H1  2300.0
3     R1   A1  H1  5000.0
```

---

**Method 2**:

The other way is using `pd.cut` to create mask for groupby

```
m = pd.cut(df.Date.dt.day, bins=[1,10,19,25,31], right=False)

df_final = (df.groupby(['Region', 'Area', 'Hq', m]).agg({'Date': 'last', 'Sales': 'sum'})
                                                   .droplevel(-1)
                                                   .reset_index())

Out[85]:
  Region Area  Hq       Date  Sales
0     R1   A1  H1 2020-01-09   4500
1     R1   A1  H1 2020-01-17   4000
2     R1   A1  H1 2020-01-23   2300
3     R1   A1  H1 2020-01-27   5000
```

Comment: Actually we have to groupby with Region, Area, Hq and Date. Because we have other Regions, Areas, Hqs too. The columns Region, area, hq and till_date should be added. So is there any to get the desired dataframe (mentioned in question) without changing index?

Comment: @NikhilGarakapati: I updated method 1 to add columns `Regions, Areas, Hqs`

Comment: These are very helpful. I wish I could think just like you. But how we generate till_date (YYYY-MM-YY format) column in the date frame?

Comment: The Method 2 is not working for the dates if it has only date. Suppose
R1---A1---H1---2020-02-21---5000, it should show R1--A1--H1---2020-02-23---5000 right?
And may i know why the dates in second method are 9,17,23,27 as we need 9,18,24,28?

Comment: because it picks the last day in each range for columns `Date`. In range `19th - 24th`, your last date is `2020-01-23`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222422/discussion-between-nikhil-garakapati-and-andy-l).

Comment: Sorry, my company network admin disabled chat. Just update your question with more info, I'll check them out when I have time.

Comment: I've updated the question. Hope this might help you in understanding what my intentions are.  Please have a look.